# node-sass binding is necessary for scss file resolving?

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, node-sass

I can only access `npm artifactory registry` in company intranet. node-sass will access github to download `bindings binary` file for current enviroment, but node-sass was installed **failed** because network reason.

How can I do?

Comment: you can try to install the entire package on another system similar to your os and copy it to the node-modules directory.

Comment: I know the way but it's not very convenient.